# Location for mounting fuse and other user specific mounts

Tags: mount, fuse

Presently I keep my personal and user level mounts in my user home directory:

```
/home
  /dummy
    /mnt
      /bindfs-to-user-x
      /borg-backup-mount
      /fuse-rclone-to-cloud
      /gocryptfs-docs
      /luks-configs-and-secrets
      /s3fs-aws-buckets
      /sshfs-to-old-box
```

The error message I see upon rebooting my workstation "systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /home" tells me Linux doesn't like my idea of stacking all those mountpoints inside `/home`, which itself is a mount on the disk.

There is no known (at least to me) specification where these types of mounts should be placed. Many online examples of mounting FUSE suggest hosing the mounts inside user home. This choice of placement, although convenient for the dummy (or just dumb me ) user, may not be right from architectural perspective, so I am trying to find better alternative locations.

One is to have them all stacked in `/mnt/dummy` an then symlink them in my home. Another option is host them somewhere in `/run/user/1000`.

Or maybe I just need to ensure correct mount/unmount order in order not to hold unmounting of the `/home` partition.

Any experience is welcome